# Why does iptables not doing DNAT for the same subnet?

Tags: iptables, nat

I have the following NAT setup:

[image]

Whereas Host 1 has a VM with IP 10.0.0.3 and HOST 2 has a VM 10.0.0.4. The NAT box will have a NAT rule such that it changes the dest IP 172.24.4.2 to 10.0.0.4:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 172.24.4.2/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.4
```

When I try to ping from VM in HOST1 to VM in HOST2 with destination IP 172.24.4.2. Some how the packet is not doing any DNAT for me.

Here is what I capture on HOST2:

```
10:15:41.017632 IP 10.0.0.3 > 172.24.4.2: ICMP echo request, id 8705, seq 0, length 64
```

It works fine if I change IP of VM in HOST2 to a different subnet.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: a NAT box MUST have its interfaces on differant networks by definition. Why are you setting up NAT in the middle of your network?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained clearer. The reason is that PC3 and PC1 have a lot of VM running and one of the VM is having 10.0.0.4 instead of PC3 has 10.0.0.4. I was trying to make things simpler but this causes confusion. I should update the question.

Comment: What's the routing table on the NAT box like?